# CollectionViewSource with Sort get sorted Items

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I have a `datagrid` which has as source `CollectionViewSource` with custom sorting and I need to get sorted items collection as can be seen in datagrid. I can get sorted description and sort source collection, but I need this collection many time.

Is there some way how to get sorted collection which enable indexation (`item[index])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CollectionViewSource's [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.view.aspx) property returns a sorted ICollectionView. Since that is an IEnumerable, you could use Linq to create a List from it, which can be accessed by index:

```
// using System.Linq;

var list = collectionView.View.Cast<object>().ToList();
var firstItem = list[0];
```

Comment: The `Cast` is fast, but `ToList` might create a copy of the whole collection.

Comment: Cut it down to `var firstItem = collectionView.View.Cast<object>().First()`

Comment: @BillLefler Yeah, but the question was how to get a list that can be access by index. `firstItem = list[0]` is just a sample access.